# How to test Failed/Denied transactions in paypal sandbox

Tags: paypal, sandbox

I am performing tests in SANDBOX.

I am implementing Website Payment Standard on my website.

I have tested successfully Completed transactions (payment_status Completed) .
I need to test Failed and Denied transactions but I am not able to do it.

If there is a test card for Failed or Denied transactions in Sandbox, please provide.

I tried with an invalid credit card to create a Failed or Denied transaction and  I got an error that appeared on the same page (I imagine that was a result of Javascript validation)  but I did not receive any reply to my IPN listener on the server and there should have been a redirection to an URL specified in the HML form as URL for invalid operations.

I understand that a result of each transaction independently of its payment status should be received by my IPN listener. It receives Completed transactions so I imagine it should received Failed or Denied ones too.

I used IPN simulator (developer.paypal.com) to create Failed/Denied transactions and I did receive them with my IPN listener so I imagine it is not a problem with the listener. I just cannot create these transactions from my page directly.

Thanks and best regards, 
Anna

Answer (score 1):

You will have to enter error code at the place of amount https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/errorcodes/

When you will set error code number at the place of amount paypal detect what type of transaction it is.

```
profile = PAYPAL_EXPRESS_GATEWAY.recurring(10502, nil,
      :description => plan.description,
      :start_date => Time.now,
      :period => 'Day',
      :frequency => 1,
      :auto_bill_outstanding => false,
      :token => params[:token],
      :max_failed_payments => 1
    )
```

in above code I set `10502` at the place of payment and when you see the doc https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/errorcodes/

error code details are:

```
10502   Invalid Data    This transaction cannot be processed. Please use a valid credit card.   The credit card used is expired.    Recurring Payments
```

and you will get APN with failed transction.

I hope this will help you